# Remove the first smallest number in a vector in C++ (and keep the order)

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have an `vector<int> number_vector` that contains `{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0}`. I need to iterate over this `number_vector`, e.g 4 times, and remove the first smallest number at each iteration, i.e at the first iteration I will remove the value `0` at the index `1`, at the next iteration I will remove the `0` that is at the index `1`, etc. I'm doing this right now the following way:

```
int n = 7;

int d = 4;

vector<int> number_vector{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0};

for (int counter = 0; counter < n - d; counter++)
{
    int index = distance(number_vector.begin(), min_element(number_vector.begin(), number_vector.end()));

    if (index != number_vector.size() - 1)
    {
        number_vector[index] = move(number_vector.back());
    }

    number_vector.pop_back();

    // number_vector.erase(number_vector.begin() + index);
}
```

The problem it's that if I run the code above, at the end `number_vector` has `{1, 0, 0, 0}` while it should have `{1, 0, 0}`, and for other cases like `n = 4`, `d = 2` and `number_vector{3, 7, 5, 9}`, the final `number_vector` has the right value, that is `79`. Some tips?

Comment: `std::vector` is the wrong choice of data structure if you want to insert/delete elements anywhere in it except the end. I recommend using `std::list`. It'll cost you `O(n)` time every deletion if you want `O(1)` space.

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger (just search online if you don't know how to use one) and inspect what the code does. That's the easiest way to find out where something goes wrong in such a small and isolated piece of code.

Comment: Notice than you change order of remaining elements. then `std::partial_sort` is a possibility.

Comment: @lucieon - not necessarily.    On small data sets in modern cpu's this can be extremely fast.   Even faster than list.  But he gives no indication of how big these vectors are.   The might be a better algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're iterating three times, not four. Secondly, if the vector isn't required, you can just use a map and pop the front iterator since it will always be the lowest value. Finally, there is no need for a swap or distance, just erase the result of min_element if it's not invalid.

Comment: First: If I use `counter < d`, the value for the second case become wrong

Second: Vector is required, once I receive a number and not a direct `{1, 0...}`

Finally: I'm removing through the index and not the value, when I remove through the value, multiple values are removed at one operation, or for some rason 1 is removed before the 0

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate from 0 to n-d, with n=7 and d=4. you will iterate from counter=0 to counter < 7-4, i.e., 3. So your loop will iterate 3 times with values 0, 1 and 2. This will remove three zeros from number_vector. So your code is behaving as expected.

I think what you want is to iterate from 0 to d. Also you are unnecessarily complicating the code by using index. You can use the iterator directly like below.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < d; counter++)
{   
    *min_element(number_vector.begin(), number_vector.end()) = *number_vector.rbegin();
    number_vector.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: `number_vector.back()` is clearer than `*number_vector.rbegin()`

Comment: Why not simply `number_vector.erase(min_element(...))`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I would say complexity.

Comment: @RemyLebeau because before removing the last element, we want to save its value at the position of the min element

Answer (score 1):

Is your `d` represents the times of pop minimum number from vector?
Then modify `counter < n - d` to `counter < d`, it will have `{1, 0, 0}`

11.04
if you want to keep the order,you can modify

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < d; ++counter)
{
    auto iter = min_element(number_vector.begin(), number_vector.end());
    number_vector.erase(iter);
}
```

PS:`std::list` maybe a better choice?

Comment: Yes, `d` represents the times to pop, but as I said: 'if I change to `d`, the other cases don't pass'